# ListView Android - displays two Items from the List < String>

Tags: android, listview, custom-adapter

I'm trying to do `ListView`. This is my code:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
String[] add1 = {"FirstName1 ","LastName1", "12-12.1993"};
String[] add2 = {"FirstName2 ","LastName2", "20-12.1993"};
// Then adds these tables to the list;
list.add(add1[0] + add1[1] + add1[2]);
list.add(add2[0] + add2[1] + add2[2]);
//I create a ListView adapter
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, list);
```

Now, My `ListView` looks like this: "FirstName1 LastName1 12-12.1993" etc.

I would like to looks like this: "FirstName1 LastName1".

I could not deleted the date, because it need to be sent to `SecondActivity`.

Comment: You can hide extra column like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14711065/hide-column-in-listview-android

Comment: Yes, @Selvin. Very clear! ;) What I did understand: `"... List<String> ... List<MyInfoClass>?"`

Comment: @Selvin Jestem początkującym programistą. Rozumiem, że lepszym podejściem byłoby zrobić osobą klasę która odpowiadałaby za tą listę tak?

Comment: Yeap ... or just [a SimpleAdapter with HashMap List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6305899/custom-listview-android/6306901#6306901) ...  for example if you remove `"Icon"` from first array and   `R.id.imageView1` from second then image would not be mapped(Adapter will show default icon)  `new String[] {"Icon","Chance","TeamID"},
                  new int[] { R.id.imageView1, R.id.textView1,R.id.textView2})` but still it will be in the HashMap ready to use later

Comment: Ok, I understand. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make new Class that hold a Person

> Person.java

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String date;


    public Person(String name, String surname, String date) {
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.date = date;
    }


   public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", surname='" + surname + '\'' +
                ", date='" + date + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Then on your main activity create an ArrayList. this Array holds a list of Persons

```
   ArrayList<Person> list =new ArrayList<>();
   list.add(new Person("FirstName1 ","LastName1", "12-12.1993"));
   list.add(new Person("FirstName2 ","LastName2", "20-12.1993"));
```

if you want to see the items in ArrayList you can type this:

```
list.get(0).toString();
```

or

```
Log.e("ArrayList","ArrayList Position 0 :"+list.get(0).toString());
```

or
   Get the name of user at position 0

```
Log.e("ArrayList","Name Position 0 :"+list.get(0).getName());
```

Finally you must Create a Custom Adapter that you pass him the Custom Array.

```
CustomAdapter adapter= new CustomAdapter(this,list);
```

just look this tutorial it will help : [Tutorial](http://androidexample.com/How_To_Create_A_Custom_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=67&aaid=92)